# How to close and open a import module like a reboot

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make my updater able to reboot so I can update without stopping the program, here is my code, and it doesn't work, anyone know how to make it work?

```py
import versionLoader
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
cwdKeep = cwd

def reboot():
    os.chdir(cwdKeep)
    versionLoader.exit()
    import versionLoader
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'versionLoader' has no attribute 'exit' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: what about it doesn't work? what is your expected result?

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken I want it to stop versionLoader, and rerun it, it doesnt do that

Comment: what is versionLoader module? Is it a module you wrote? I can't find it...where did you get it, install it from?

Comment: It is a script I made, python will run the script if you import it like I did, you can test it by making a versonLoader.py file, and adding print("versionLoader loaded") or something

Comment: maybe the error is due to importing your module twice. have you consider using `importlib.reload()` [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can reload a already imported package by using the reload function in the importlib package docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload)